# Get the value from inline assembly code

Tags: visual-c++, x86, inline-assembly

I have an inline assembly code like this

```
__asm
{
    MOV dword ptr [esp+4], 12345678h
}
```

I want to get the value of at [esp+4] in a separate variable before 12345678h is written there, which I can use further in my c++ code.

Comment: 1. `__asm` is a non-standard, non-portable extension to C++. Which compiler are you using? 2. Which manual for your compiler have you used in your research?

Comment: I am using Visual C++ 2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydwz5zc6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which I found in less than five minutes, variable identifiers are valid within `__asm` blocks. I then found a relevant example by clicking the "[Accessing C or C++ data in __asm blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fabdxz08%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)" link under the "*What do you want to know more about?*" section of that manual:

> A great convenience of inline assembly is the ability to refer to C or
>   C++ variables by name. An __asm block can refer to any symbols,
>   including variable names, that are in scope where the block appears.
>   For instance, if the C variable var is in scope, the instruction
>
> `__asm mov eax, var`
>
> stores the value of var in EAX.